# Use LIKE/regex with variable in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I'm trying to find all documents whose text contains the word test. The below works fine:

```
@tweets = Tweet.any_of({ :text => /.*test.*/ })
```

However, I want to be able to search for a user supplied string. I thought the below would work but it doesn't:

```
searchterm = (params[:searchlogparams][:searchterm])
@tweets = Tweet.any_of({ :text => "/.*"+searchterm+".*/" })
```

I've tried everything I could think of, anyone know what I could do to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should add "i" at the end there /.*test.*/i to make that work without being case sensitive.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
searchterm = (params[:searchlogparams][:searchterm])
@tweets = Tweet.any_of({ :text => Regexp.new ("/.*"+searchterm+".*/") })
```

or

```
searchterm = (params[:searchlogparams][:searchterm])
@tweets = Tweet.any_of({ :text => /.*#{searchterm}.*/ })
```

Comment: What I need to do if i want to search like there is location Mumbai and I am passing the location like  Mumbai, Maharashtra , India. But it is not searching.. here is my query Event.any_of(location: /.*mumbai maharashtra.*/is).entries. Its not working but if I pass a mumbai then its working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 15):

There is nothing wrong with the mongodb regex query. The problem is passing variable to ruby regex string. You cannot mix string with regex like normal strings

Instead

```
 "/.*"+searchterm+".*/"
```

try this

```
  >>searchterm = "test"
  >>"/#{searchterm}/"
  >> "/test/"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Ramesh. I had to remove the " at start and end and then your example worked perfectly. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

```
@tweets = Tweet.any_of({ :text => Regexp.new (".*"+searchterm+".*") })
```

is ok and have result

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by doing:

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions => {:field => /regex/i})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@tweets = Tweet.any_of({ :text => Regexp.new ("/.*"+searchterm+".*/") })
```

is work, but no result

```
@tweets = Tweet.any_of({ :text => Regexp.new (".*"+searchterm+".*") })
```

is ok and have result

```
@tweets = Tweet.any_of({ :text => /.*#{searchterm}.*/ })
```

is work, no result

My mongoid version is 3.1.3  and ruby version is 1.9.3